# asp.net webform - How to persist a object Instance beetwen pages

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, web, webforms

I am using ASP.NET web Form and I Have an app that persist an object instance in a Session variable but when several clients are connected, i have a big  problem in the performance, exist an option for avoid session variables?

I need the object instance because i need only modify the data in memory and the save the data in DB on client demand.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have several options - two that come immediate to mind are to either offload your session state to an out of memory option like SQL or a distributed cache (Redis, for example - though technically these are only out of memory from the web server's perspective) or push the object state into the page's view state.

Of the two options view state will probably have less development overhead, but offloading the session state to something like Redis is typically preferred from a best practices standpoint since it lets you better control how long the object state is valid and cuts down on how much you're having to transmit to the client.  This is doubly true for sensitive data.

See the links below for a bit more information on each option.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_cache